# Automate backing up everything in each folder

Tags: powershell

I'm in need of automating a repetitive task: I have an application that has two WCF services and one IIS published website. My target is a Staging machine used by QA. Every time code changes are made, I have to deploy to a folder as below (ignore the red outlines):

[image: Backup Plan]

So the root folder is, say, `D:\Application\My Project\v2\`

Within this root, there are three folders:

- `ServiceExternal\`
- `ServiceInternal\`
- `Web\`

Within each of these three folders, there is a folder called `!Releases\` and this folder has many folders named in this format: YYYY-MM-DD-##

Example: I had three deployments yesterday, so I made three folders in the `!Releases\` directory (for each of three apps) as:

- `!Releases\2019-10-15-01\`
- `!Releases\2019-10-15-02\`
- `!Releases\2019-10-15-03\`

Each time, I just copied the file related to the application to the respective folder before pasting in the new files/binaries/configs. This is not a good way to do things but I had to inherit this and we are a bit under governance and cannot yet go full DevOps and pipeline this process.

I need to automate this through a PS script:

1. Loop through all folders in root directory (There can be more folders and not just three)
2. In each folder, call this app folder, create a new folder within `!Releases\`:

   1. Folder to be created of today's date + today's index (2 digits)
   2. If today's date folder is found, get the index bit and +1
3. Once folder created, copy *.* (except the `!Releases\` folder) from the app folder to this new folder
4. That's it.

Here is what I managed to do so far:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory | ForEach-Object { }
```

And that's about it. I get a dump of everything. At this stage, I need help.

Comment: Why are the images no longer working?

Comment: Currently your question is asking "please implement this algorithm for me". Please try a little harder.